# Github pages Build Error: The jekyll-theme-hydejack theme could not be found

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I am trying to publish a github blog page, which I was able to publish to github.io page without an issue 2 months ago, but it throws an error now. I can still successfully build a jekyll theme locally.

When I push it to github, however, it throws a build error message saying:

> Error: The jekyll-theme-hydejack theme could not be found.

I am using jekyll-theme-hydejack version 9.0.4 which I specified in my Gemfile, Gemfile.lock, config.yml

Here's my git build error link for more info: https://github.com/dailyole/dailyole.github.io/runs/4758386396?check_suite_focus=true

Here's a screenshot of my local cmd results and my blog successfully running on my local server:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 6):

I had same error before while executing hydejack theme in github pages.
I found the solution for me that works properly.

1. Find _config.yml
2. comment line code "theme: jekyll-theme-hydejack" into "#theme: jekyll-theme-hydejack"
3. add line code "remote_theme: hydecorp/hydejack@v9"
4. commit and push to github

I hope it works for your problem too.

Comment: To close the loop on this answer, it's easy to check which themes Github pages has [here](https://pages.github.com/themes/), and if you need some other theme, use ```remote_theme```

Comment: For those who are just starting their website now, rather than updating from an older version: you probably forked the wrong branch of the Hydejack repository. There's one for Github Pages [specifically called `gh-pages`](https://github.com/hydecorp/hydejack-starter-kit/tree/gh-pages), which has the above config change built in.

Answer (score 0):

Open your `_config.yml` file.

Remove `theme` key and add only `remote_theme: hydecorp/hydejack`. Push to github.